# "Change password" wants to change WRONG Stack Exchange account

Tags: support, bug, login, user-accounts

I have two SE logins - an old one I'd prefer not to use, `davidbak -at- gmail.com`, and a new one that I want to switch to, `david -at bakins-bits.com`.

I can't log in with the new one.  Perhaps it is a password issue?  Ok, I try to change my password of the "new" account here:

[image]

And the change dialog shows the *other* account here:

[image]

A possible clue for someone:  Notice all three accounts in the image show "Used 1 min ago" but I only logged in on the first one.  (And I have no idea what the third one is or how it is different.)

Really, I'd like to delete my "old" account but of course I can't as long as I can't log in on the new one.

(BTW, IDC about "exposing" my email addresses here, so I didn't bother obscuring them - it would have just made it harder to ask the question anyway.)

Comment: Hmm you only seem to have one passworded login set up. The `@bakins-bits` email is actually connected to a Google account and does not have a password, and thus cannot have the password "changed" because it's not that kind of credential. It shouldn't be showing up under the Stack Exchange section at all. What happens if you click the Add button at the bottom and type in that email and the password you want for it?

Comment: @animuson - yes that worked! How should I resolve this question?  (BTW it is darn hard to figure out how to _log out_ of the site!  Certainly didn't expect it to be over at the "show the other stacks you're in" icon at the top left.  Expected it at the top-right hamburger icon or somewhere on the profile page - where it is conspicuously missing!)

Comment: WAIT! I still apparently don't know my left from my right.  It is the top-LEFT icon where I expected it, the top-RIGHT where I finally found it.